# How deselect a radio button on select of another in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have used chiclet slicer to achieve radio button,
In my case from 3 measures I have taken 3 chiclet slicers, While clicking on a single radio button it is working fine, but on selecting another how to deselect the other two radio buttons.
I have data in 3 different measures "daily", "weekly" and "monthly".
My requirement is on the select of any those rest two options should be deselected, which is the default behavior of the radio button.
Or you can suggest me if there is any other way to implement the radio button.

[image]

Comment: What about three [buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-buttons) and three [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks)?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement the same need.

- Buttons + Bookmark (built-in)
- Slicer + Switch (built-in)
- custom visuals in the store

In general, I prefer built-in Power BI functionalities because for enterprise production solution you do not want to rely on custom tools not officially supported by the software vendor.
Therefore, if your project is a real work then my suggestion is to use the Buttons + Bookmark built-in functionality. For your case you need:

1. [Buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-buttons)
2. [Bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks)

In practice, create 3 buttons: Daily, Weekly and Monthly.
Next, create a bookmark with the default view, calling it Default.
Then, update one bookmark for each of the three view. It could simply be hiding or showing a visualization in the same page. Please note that a hidden visualization will not trigger any computation when the page is opened.
Finally, set the `action` of clicking the button to direct the user toward the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

I've always achieved this using the standard slicer and a hidden table with the needed labels and/or values.

1. Create a table by using "Enter data" or by using DAX, and put in it your 3 labels "Daily","Weekly","Monthly", I will call the table "MyTable" and the column "SwitchLabel"
2. Create a slicer with field "SwitchLabel", in the selection control enable "single select". (you can change the orientation in the "general" section).
3. Create a switch measure like the one below:

```
SalesSwitch = SWITCH(   SELECTEDVALUE('MyTable'[SwitchLabel])
    ,"Weekly", [WeeklySalesmeasure]
    ,"Daily", [DailySalesmeasure]
    ,[DefaultMeasure] --optional "else", if nothing matches or there are multiple selections
)
```

4. Put the "SalesSwitch" measure in the charts.
5. The slicer/filter on the "switch" table must be present on every page that uses the measures, otherwise (without filter), it will always fall in the default case.

One limit of this solution is that it cannot change the X axis, in fact you are just calling different measures based on the selection.
If you need to also change the X-axis use Seymour's method with buttons and bookmarks.

Comment: Good contribution. In the limitations of Switch, besides creating redundant measures and useless dimensions, I would also mention performance issues because introducing a SWITCH function (that is compiled as IF) negatively impacts both the execution time and the cache.